# How to show text when clicking on an image to a div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to post an image of 2 DIVs, separated by a black line , the one on the left have 4 images and what I want is:

When I click on any of the buttons it will reveal a text in the right DIV and when I press another image it reveals, too, another text. I have no idea how I can do that, that's why I'm here asking for help.

If you have any ideas about the subject, like what I must use, or sources that you can find because I didn't find anything related.

I've searched about this in JavaScript revealing a text from a button, but nothing that could help me.

For your better understanding i will show you how is the final result, how it should look. 
http://prntscr.com/7krf5h

Of course without the arrows pointing, and the image in the right div, it will disappear, i just need  the text and show the text, but i think u understand the content.

Comment: It would hard for us to 'reveal' this to you without your code

Comment: simply you would need to use jquery. bind click event to the div containing image and the one revealing the text. when you click on div containing the image the div containing the text will have its text changed. Many examples...See click event in jquery here: https://api.jquery.com/click/

Comment: i will try it. I can show the code with no problems, i didnt show in the post because i thought it wouldnt be needed :)

Comment: well to show u the code i need to show u the design so u can understand. This is the layout http://prntscr.com/7krdr8    There are 4 images like i said and a div in the right side, when i click in any of the images, it must reveal a text in the right div. Thats what i want :)

Comment: I edited the main post, so u can better understand

Comment: Why don't you start by creating a JSFiddle of your HTML at least? That way people might be willing to make some jQuery suggestions to help. Keep in mind that people are volunteering to help you, make it as easy as possible for them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you're trying to setup a slideshow of some sort. One way you can do it is to create two lists, a hidden one for the slide data and another visible one for the list of slides on the left-hand side. Then, you can grab the necessary data from the hidden list based on index. Here's an example fiddle that will highlight what I mean: http://jsfiddle.net/ethueuhj/1/ (in the fiddle, you can change the `data-bg` attribute to a computer background, tablet background, et al).

```
$(function() {
    function setSlide(index) {
        var slide = $('.slide-data li').eq(index);
        $('.slide-container').css({ "background-image": "url('" + slide.data('bg') + "')" });
        $('.slide-container').html(slide.html());
    }

    $('.slides li').click(function() {
        setSlide($(this).index());
    });

    // Default slide
    setSlide(0);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use jquery in order to achieve what you want.

Also, you need to change the text of the div when you click on another div tag. For this, you need to user inner html.

Here is the sample code, you can try it.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("name_of_image_div_tag_here").click(function(){
    alert("The image was clicked.");
    document.getElementById("name_of_text_div_tag_here").innerHTML = "Sample text to display";
    });
});
```

Comment: well, i tested but maybe im forgetting something? i took a print screen http://prntscr.com/7krauw , so u can see ur code inside the body tag. I changed the first query function $("name_of_image_div_tag_here") and i put the id of the div which contains the <img> tag. And then the document.getElementById, i put the id of the text div. But when i run the website, the click doesnt work. The event doesnt show anything when i click the image.

Comment: Include jQuery from a CDN, like Google

Comment: add this link in head under script tag and src attribute: http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-1.11.3.min.js